# Add intellisense to Atom

Tags: atom-editor, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code if you install the typings(the new tsd) it enables intellisense for the given typing. For example if you execute

```
$ typings install node --ambient --save
```

in the base folder of your project, you get intellisense for node.

Is there a way to achieve the same with Atom, or it's not supported?

Answer (score 0):

Atom doesn't support Typescript intellisense out of the box, but it has a great plugin system.

Install the [Atom Typescript](https://atom.io/packages/atom-typescript) plugin. It provides many features for working with Typescript, including intellisense.

Comment: I think what the OP was asking for is not the missing support for Typescript files (which is what this plugin provides), but a way of replicating VSCode's automatic typings download and application to non-Typescript code and libraries. Like his example with Node.js files, which are not Typescript files, but VSC still gives you intellisense out of the box. I was with Atom from the very beginning, but this feature made me switch to VS Code.